# Swift equivalent of this ActionScript line of code?

Tags: swift

I'm translating the ActionScript code from [this](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-bsp-trees-to-generate-game-maps--gamedev-12268) development tutorial into swift because I'm trying to teach myself BSP. I came across a line of code I don't fully understand.

```
var splitH:Boolean = FlxG.random() > 0.5;
```

Somehow, they are casting an integer as a boolean. What would be the swift equivalent of this line? It doesn't make any sense to me. How are they casting a random value as a boolean as well? Swift doesn't allow this sort of "cross-breeding".

This is my attempt at it so far:

```
var splitH = Int(arc4random_uniform(2) + 1)
var splitB = false
```

I split the line into two values because I don't know how to make this as one line. Is this the correct approach?

This doesn't work:

```
var splitH:Bool = Int(arc4random_uniform(2) + 1)
```

Comment: `It doesn't make any sense to me. How are they casting a random value as a boolean as well?` — operator `>` is doing exactly this, in `Swift` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator here as well.

Something along the lines of

```
var splitH = arc4random_uniform(100) > 50 ? true : false
```

or simply

```
var splitH = arc4random_uniform(100) > 50
```

Answer (score 0):

N.B.: Assuming `FlxG.random()` is returning uniform random between `0.0` and `1.0`. If it has different distribution it won't work, ofc.

If we're talking about pre-4.2 Swift your line is equivalent to:

```
let splitH: Bool = arc4random_uniform(2) == 1
```

In `Swift 4.2+` you may just use something like this:

```
let splitH: Bool = Double.random(in: 0.0 ..< 1.0) > 0.5
```